# I want validation on textbox for phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want validation on text box for phone number which allowed

Allowed chars:

```
space + ( ) - 0-9
```

(or `+` can be first char after trim, like `(+61) 312 405 786` or `+61 312 405 786`)

Length: min 8, max 16.

Please help.

I have tried but I am not able to get correct Regex.

function phNum(val) {

    var subjectString = val;
    var regexObj = /^\(?([0-9][- ]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{3})$/;

    if (regexObj.test(subjectString)) {
        var formattedPhoneNumber = subjectString.replace(regexObj, "+61$1$2$3");

        document.getElementById('a').value = formattedPhoneNumber;
    }
}

nmn

But its not works for me............

Comment: You want us to write the regular expression for you?

Comment: Unless you state what you have tried and where you're stuck, this question is likely to be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Note that if the data _must_ be in that format, you should validate server-side as well. Client-side validation is easily bypassed.

Comment: go here: http://regexlib.com/ and search for "phone" or similar.

Comment: Boom `^\(?\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-\s]?([0-9]{3})[-\s]?([0-9]{3})[-\s]?([0-9]{3})$`. Deal with it. Closing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get a regex for your needs

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

```
var regex = new RegExp("sum regex");


if (input.val().match(regex))
{
   //true
}
else
{
  //false
}
```

Comment: "sum"? Do you by any chance mean "Some"?

Comment: yap sorry about that :) my comps word correction is killing me. PS:do you need exact regex?

Comment: oh sorry! I'm not the poster. Sanjeev is the poster.